# Можно ли сделать это только при помощи css?

Tags: css3

Можно ли сделать такое в css? имею в виду эти переходы.
[image: картинка]

Comment: Где-то я уже писал, что сами градиенты не проблема. Проблема в их адаптивности при изменении размеров. Т.е. если делать "один в один" и для фиксированных размеров, то ничего сложного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фиксированных размеров, как-то так:

```css
.waves {
  height: 348px;
  width: 423px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(circle, hsla(215, 49%, 60%, 0.75), hsla(215, 39%, 0%, 0.35)), 
    radial-gradient(circle at -115px 2750px, #3f71b5 87%, transparent 87.1%), 
    radial-gradient(circle at -292px 2000px, #305ea3 87%, transparent 87.1%), 
    linear-gradient(4deg, #3f71b5 73%, #305ea3 74%);
}
```

```html
<div class="waves"></div>
```

Comment: Похоже градиенты, - это один из твоих козырей :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не то, чтобы козыри... Просто люблю рисовать. Правда, в последнее время, все худ.материалы стали неподъёмно дорогие ;-( Поэтому с масла и карандаша приходится перебираться в пиксели.

Comment: может тебе заняться 3D? Даже здесь ощущается объём, работа со светотенью! Я понимаю, что это радиальные градиенты, но в разных руках, они разные получаются :).

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я лет пять назад занимался предметным моделированием и архитектурной визуализацией в 3DMax на заказ. Но, домашние компы не тянут нормально, поэтому тоже забросил.